# How to UNBLOCK a specific domain from Google Search results (stackoverflow.com)

Tags: support, search, google, google-chrome

For some reason I cannot at all see search results from https://stackoverflow.com

Video: https://i.stack.imgur.com/soqrF.jpg

I must have blocked it unwittingly at some point, and I can’t find any way to undo this action.

According to Google Forums - there should be a tab in my Google Account → *Security* → *Restricted Sites*

But it isn't there. Any ideas?

Comment: You have a bunch of Chrome extensions there. Are any of them ad blockers like ublock origin? Perhaps you blocked it through an extension. You could also try doing the same search in incognito mode which doesn't load any extensions to see if it's still blocked.

Comment: If it isn't, try disabling your extensions one by one to find out which one is the culprit.

Comment: It suspiciously looks like an extension - SO is the first search result for a frame and then blinks out of existence afterwards suggesting something is removing the node that wraps the search result depending on the link. Try to remember which extension does that. P.s. That's why I use as little extra fluff on browsers as possible

Comment: I feel really dumb but it was indeed a chrome extension, one that flew under the radar. Appreciate the comments that pointed this out

Answer (score 5):

At first sight this question might look a question that could be asked in Web Applications and in Super User...

Web Applications: Unfortunately troubleshooting like questions are off-topic on this site.

Super User: This site has the following tags:

- [troubleshooting](https://superuser.com/tags/troubleshooting): Troubleshooting is a form of problem solving that uses logical, systematic steps to solve the problem.
- [google-chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome): Google's web browser available on both mobile and desktop platforms.
- [google-search](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-search): Mostly off-topic at Super User, questions are better suited to WebApps.stackexchange.com. Questions about the interaction between a browser and the website may be on topic.

---

Things to try when troubleshooting web applications (in the order that I usually follow)

- Try using your favorite web browser in private / incognito / safe mode with all the extensions disabled. If the web app allows anonymous users try first without signing-in in your account, then try signing-in in your account.
- Try using using different items; which and how many combinations will depend on the issue and your possibilities, but at least try changing the items of a couple of categories:

  - Web browsers
  - User accounts
  - Internet Connections (Ethernet / Wi-Fi / others)
  - Networks (Work, Home, VPN, etc)
  - Devices (Computers, Smartphones, Tables, Game Console, ...)
- If you still doesn't have idea of what is blocking the app to work as expected, open the web browser developer tools. First look at the console, it might have relevante messages. Then look at the other tools.
- Search the web (this includes Stack Exchange) for similar problems.